Switch to change navbar-light to navbar-dark
in my ASP.Net I have following hamburger menu:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">

Besides I am using following project as a switch to switch to dark mode:
https://github.com/coliff/dark-mode-switch -> dark-mode-switch.min.js
This works fine to change buttons etc that are in CSS, but probably I wont be able to use it to change navbar-light to navbar-dark in class.
So I do not know if it has to be done in that JavaScript File mentioned above or if it can be done by CSS as well.
What would be the way to include it into the rest?

If you check the files, the dark mode add "data-theme", "dark" through js file to the body and the associated css act on body child elements with classes .bg-black, .bg-dark bg-white...which you have in your nav (bg-white is black in dark-mode) So I think it should work

Hi,thanks, you are right. I could do it that way:
[data-theme="dark"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
